# Selector to get value of showing subtitle(caption) of video.js

Tags: video.js

I want to get as a sentence of showing subtitle(caption) of video.js when a user paused a video. Is there are any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer you're looking for is .vjs-text-track. For example, to get the captions and/or subtitles text using jQuery, you would use:

```
var currentText = $('.vjs-text-track').text();
```